# Cannot set ViewState.Setters in Blend

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, blend

I have created custom control :

```
public sealed partial class CustomControl : UserControl
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets and gets the IsWide property.
        /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
        /// </summary>
        public bool IsWide
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsWideProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(IsWideProperty, value);
                Debug.WriteLine("IsWide executed");
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsWideProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IsWide), typeof(bool), typeof(CustomControl), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnWide));

        private static void OnWide(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("OnWide executed");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public CustomControl()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

I create instance of this control in `Page`,

```
<ctr:CustomControl x:Name="FormattingBar" />
```

I added `VisualStateGroup` using `Blend`.

```
     <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdaptiveVisualStateGroup">
               <VisualState x:Name="VisualStateWide">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource WideMinWidth}" />
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

But when I try to set `IsWide` property in `VisualState` using `Blend`, 
I got this error :

[image: Property Sets Error]

So, I coded this setter manually,

```
<VisualState.Setters>
    <Setter Target="FormattingBar.IsWide" Value="True" />
</VisualState.Setters>
```

Run it, I check in debug window `VisualStateWide` state indeed triggered when I resize app, but `IsWide` property never get sets.

[image: Debug Window]